# Load navigation properties necessary for a method in POCO in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties, poco, eager-loading

Please see the following example of my problem.

After I received the `result` variable from the `Calculate()` method the EF context is disposed. If I later invoke the `DoMethod()` on this `result` I get an error, because the EF navigation property `SomeObjects` aren't loaded.

I could think of the following solutions to prevent this problem?

1. Eagerly Loading `SomeObjects` within the `Calculate()` method (`xyList = context.Xys.Include(x => x.SomeObjects).ToList();`) (unnecessary loads of this property if not used later)
2. Don't close the DB context or use a global context (very bad!)
3. Load the missing EF navigation property within the `DoMethod()`

I would go with the third one, because the `DoMethod()` isn't always invoked and thus I don't need `SomeObjects` if it's not.

My question is how to realize the third solution? And is it the right way? Querying out of a POCO to get the necessary data seems to be a bit odd.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     ...
     Xy result = Calculation.Calculate();
     ...
     //Maybee this method is invoked
     result.DoMethod();
  }
}

// POCO class
public class XY
{
  public virtual List<Xz> SomeObjects { get; set; } 

  public void DoMethod()
  {
    foreach (var obj in SomeObjects)
    {
       ...
    }
  }
}

class Calculation
{
   public static Xy Calculate() {
      Xy result;
      using (var context = new MyContext())
      {
         xyList = context.Xys.ToList();
         ...
         result = xyList[calculatedIndex];
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options I've tried or thought of.  #3 is one attempt at what you indicate is your preferred approach.

---

**1. Only doing the calculation at the last moment.**

This has the overhead of creating context every time result is needed, but defers using context until a result is needed.  Your use case dictates whether this is helpful or not.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     ...
     Calculation calc = new Calculation();
     ...
     //Maybe this method is invoked
     calc.GetResult().DoMethod();
  }
}

class Calculation
{      
    public Xy GetResult();
    {
      Xy result;
      using (var context = new MyContext())
      {
         xyList = context.Xys.ToList();
         ...
         result = xyList[calculatedIndex];
      }
      return result;
    }
}
```

---

**2. Caching the result and keeping the context alive**

This is your option #2, but without a global context (which you rightly were concerned about).  If you are concerned about not disposing of the context, take a look at this: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html.
Aside from the memory overhead of the loaded Context, I don't see a downside to this. EF will defer loading `SomeObjects` until you first need them via a call to `DoMethod()`.  You are trading keeping the context around for not having to load SomeObject unless required.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     ...
     Calculation calc = new Calculation(new MyContext());
     //use result, perhaps many times
     /*something with calc.Result; */

     ...
     //Maybe this method is invoked
     calc.Result.DoMethod();

     //context will not go away until Calculation does
  }
}
class Calculation
{
    private MyContext context = null;
    private Xy result = null;

    public Calculation(MyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Xy Result {
        get {
            if (result == null) {
                result = Calculate();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    private Xy Calculate();
    {
      Xy result;
      xyList = context.Xys.ToList();
      ...
      result = xyList[calculatedIndex];
      return result;
    }
}
```

---

**3. Implementing your option #3 via a Dynamic Proxy**

This allows wrapping the XY in a proxy that behaves like an XY, but intercepting the call to `DoMethod` to get a new context so that `SomeObjects` can resolve in the  new context.  I used Castle Dynamic Proxy, available in the Castle.Core project, which you can simply add via Nuget.  There's enough conceptual overhead, that I think  it might be a counter-proof of concept. I.e., it demonstrates that keeping the context around so that `SomeObjects` can be lazy loaded against the original context may be the cleanest idea.  And again, refer to arguments in http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html for why it may be ok to keep the context around.  BTW, that article comes out of dialog with the EF developer team.

using Castle.DynamicProxy;

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     ...
     Calculation calc = new Calculation(new MyContext());
     //use result, perhaps many times
     /*something with calc.Result; */

     ...
     //Maybe this method is invoked
     calc.Result.DoMethod();


  }
}

// POCO class
public class XY
{
  public virtual List<Xz> SomeObjects { get; set; } 

  public virtual void DoMethod()
  {
    foreach (var obj in SomeObjects)
    {
       ...
    }
  }
}

public class XYInterceptor : XY, IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.Name == "DoMethod")
        {
            //get a new context so that we can have SomeObjects resolve properly
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                var newXy = context.Xys.Find(((XY)invocation.InvocationTarget).Id);
                newXy.DoMethod();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Any other method goes straight through
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
    }
}

public class Calculation
{
    private XY result = null;

    public XY Result {
        get {
            if (result == null) {
                result = Calculate();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    private XY Calculate()
    {
      XY proxyResult;
      using (var context = new MyContext())
      {
          xyList = context.Xys.ToList();
          ...
          Xy realResult = xyList[calculatedIndex];
          proxyResult = (new ProxyGenerator()).CreateClassProxyWithTarget<XY>(realResult, new XYInterceptor());
          return proxyResult;
      }
    }
}
```

One annoying facet of my third sketch is that it does not update the Result with the new XY.  That would need to be made to work before it's really ready for use.

Comment: Added an example that caches result for as often as it is needed, and keeps context alive for duration of calculation.

Comment: Essentially, this is your option #2, but the context is not global.

Comment: BTW, if your concern is that you feel like you *must* dispose of the context, see this discussion which argues that there are many situations where not disposing of context is ok http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html.

Comment: I've added a third sketch, which is an attempt to use your preferred approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborated answer.